# How to save a css change made dynamically with user input?

Tags: javascript, css, dom, sass, styles

I am building an e-commerece site. And I'm using a heart font icon which acts as a tool which users can use to favorite an item in the site. So when a user clicks on the icon, it changes it color to red from black. How can I save that change in the css ? Btw, Im using reactjs.

```
    const addToWishList = (e) => {
    e.target.style.color = 'red';
    e.preventDefault();
    const parent = e.target.parentElement;
    const itemName = parent.childNodes[2].childNodes[0].textContent;
    const itemImg = parent.childNodes[1].childNodes[0].src;
    const obj = {
        item: itemName,
        img: itemImg
    };

    wishlist.push(obj);
};
```

Im using this code to change the color of the icon, but how can I say the updated changes. As the color changes back to black after refreshing the browser.

Comment: Are you asking how to update an element's class? You generally don't go and change the actual document stylesheet. You should add some JS, CSS, and HTML to your question as a [mcve].

Comment: No, not to update. I can update with a simple code like this " e.target.style.color = 'red' but if a user has favorited am item, I want to be able to indicate that can Item is already favorited by making the font color to remain red instead of the default black

Comment: Is your question then: "How do I save the favourite setting to my server so that when the user reloads the page the icon for that item is already red?"

Comment: yes, you think I should change it to that exact question.

Comment: Yes. Because your current question doesn't explain that context. But you'd have to explain how the item is loaded into the page (is it an object?), and how you update the server (`fetch`?). Then we can properly help you. The more details the better.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure about how to do this the way you intend but I will just post here how I think this needs to be approached.

Since **each** user will have **different** items which are in their favorites, you need to find a way to store which items are favorites for each user.

When the particular user accesses their account, you need to first fetch the data regarding the favorite items of the user and then  automatically change the color of the icon to red if the **current page** contains any such favorite items.

Storing the fetched data in a session variable would be helpful in making changes to it.

Also you need to include the code to make the necessary changes when user adds new item or removes item from their favorites!